# OPENCV in Pycharm is showing me an array Value Error

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

The issue I am facing is that it shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\WakeUp\Wake Up.py", line 74, in <module>
    if EYE_AR_THRESH > ear:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is the code:

```
    if EYE_AR_THRESH > ear:
        COUNTER += 1


        if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
            if not ALARM_ON:
                ALARM_ON = True

                t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
                           args = (args["alarm"],))
                t.deamon = True
                t.start()

                cv2.putText (frame, "DROWSINESS ALERT!" , (10,30),
                         cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0,0,255), 2)

    else:
        COUNTER = 0
        ALARM_ON = False
```

I don't know how to fix this, please help!

Comment: what is `EYE_AR_THRESH`, where is it defined, what value does it hold, ...?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it asks for this format:
since the terminal gives a.all() OR a.any(), where "a" is not defined.

So in this case, put it in the value missing: here, we do:
if (EYE_AR_THRESH > ear).any():

as this can cause an array of different values for our answer.